# VBA Error 52 on a function that tests if a file exists

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to pull text from a bunch of XML files into Word. I'm working from a list of files and have found that some of them don't actually exist in the folder.  So, I'm using [this function](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T011831_Determining_If_a_File_Exists.html) to check whether the files actually exist before opening them. But I'm still getting error 52 (Bad file name or number).

This is the function:

```
Function FileThere(FileName As String) As Boolean
    FileThere = (Dir(FileName) > "")
End Function
```

And this is the code I'm calling it from:

```
Sub PullContent()

Dim docList As Document

Dim docCombinedFile As Document

Dim objFileListTable As Table

Dim objRow As Row

Dim strContent As String

Dim strFileCode As String
'Code # for the current file. (Pulled in temporarily, output to the Word doc.)

Dim strFilename As String
'Name of  XML file. Created based on strFileCode

Set docCombinedFile = Documents.Add
'The new doc which will list all warnings

Dim strXml As String
'String variable that holds the entire content of the data module

Dim strInvalidCodes
'String listing any invalid file codes. Displayed at the end.

Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\kelly.keck\Documents\Triton MTS\IETMs - Test\IETMList.docx"
Set docList = Documents("IETMList.docx")

Set objFileListTable = docList.Tables(1)

For Each objRow In objFileListTable.Rows


    strFileCode = objRow.Cells(4).Range.Text
    strFileCode = Left(strFileCode, Len(strFileCode) - 2)
    strFilename =  strFileCode & ".xml"
    strPath = "C:\Applications\xml\"

    If FileThere(strPath & strFileCode) = True Then


        'MsgBox (strPath & strFilename)


            strXml = FSO.OpenTextFile(strPath & strFilename).ReadAll

    Else

        strInvalidCodes = strInvalidCodes & vbCr & strFileCode


    End If

Next

MsgBox ("The following filenames were invalid: " & vbCr & strInvalidCodes)


End Sub
```

Getting this error seems to defeat the purpose of having a function to check if a file exists, but I'm not sure what's wrong with the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but this hasn't had an accepted answer yet.

I generally use this method to test if a file exists, and your code uses FileSystemObject already so could use that reference.

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileExists = oFSO.FileExists(FileName)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to be sure that FileThere is actually returning the Boolean value you intend. It would be more reliable if you checked the Len property (the number of characters) or checked whether it actually returns the empty string.

The following is more verbose than absolutely necessary in order to make the logic clear. If you were to use Len, instead, then you'd check Len(Dir(FileName)) > 0

```
Function FileThere(FileName as String) as Boolean
  Dim bFileExists as Boolean
  If Dir(FileName) = "" Then
    bFileExists = False
  Else
    bFileExists = True
  End If
  FileThere = bFileExists
End Function
```

Comment: Good call on making sure it's actually returning a Boolean. When running this, I get a compile error ("Function call on left hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object.")